# adding a payload file to a bootable USB drive created by mkusb-plug

Tags: mkusb

I'm trying to create a bootable USB drive that will contain FreeDOS *and* a BIOS update file. When I use `mkusb-plug` with a 4GB USB drive, it creates a single FAT12 partition with just enough space for FreeDOS. So there's no space left to put the payload file and the GUI doesn't seem to have any options to increase the size of the partition.

- I've tried editing the primary partition to increase its size.
- I've tried the `mkusb-plug` option to create a second USBDATA partition in FAT32 format. But FreeDOS doesn't map a drive to this partition, so I can't access the payload file there.

Comment: 1. Are you cloning from a FreeDOS file `FD12LITE.img` or `FD12FULL.img` or something else? 2. What is the size of the payload file?

Comment: Yes, the LITE file.

Comment: Running Ubuntu I can use `sudo -H gparted` to increase the size of the FAT partition to 127 MiB, which creates 96 MiB free space. Will it be enough for your payload file?

Comment: The payload file is about 14MB so, yes, that should be enough. I’ll look at using gparted and report back later today. Thanks.

Comment: That's great :-) A more complicated alternative is to use gparted to create a second partition with for example size **512 MiB** and the **FAT 16** file system. I checked that FreeDOS will recognize such a file system at boot as D: and FreeDOS could create and read a file in it.

Comment: Thanks. My gparted objected to using FAT12, but then I added a second partition and everything went smoothly. My laptop is happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Running Ubuntu I can use `sudo -H gparted` to increase the size of the original FAT partition of `FD12LITE` to 127 MiB, which creates 96 MiB free space.
- A more complicated alternative is to use `sudo -H gparted` to create a **second partition** with for example

  - **size 512 MiB** and
  - **FAT 16** file system.

  I checked that FreeDOS will recognize such a file system at boot as `D:` and FreeDOS could create and read a file in it.